# Turn off rvm greeting on login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, rvm, foreman

I have problem with foreman and rvm - foreman generates start and stop init.d scripts for resque worker.
The problem is that start script tries to write pid of new worker in file, but writes it with rvm message `Using /home/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247` that appears on login.

Of course, I may edit generated script to cut off that part, but then I'll need to do that every time scripts are regenerated.

Here is how foreman tries to save pid:

```
su - $USERNAME -c 'cd /home/path/to/current; export PORT=5000; bundle exec rake environment resque:work QUEUE=* RAILS_ENV=production >> /var/log/app_name/job-1.log 2>&1 & echo $!' > $PIDDIR/job.1.pid
```

How can I disable that rvm message? Or any other solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are using `cd` to load ruby, the `Using` message is most likely coming from it, the ad hook solution would be to silence it:

```
cd /home/path/to/current >/dev/null
```

there is also a flag to silence the message, but it might not work with older `.rvmrc` files:

```
echo rvm_use_flag=0 >> ~/.rvmrc
```

Comment: Thanks, using `rvm_use_flag=0` removed the message.